# Get an array of property values from an object array in typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript

```
class Test{
    constructor(private Name: string, private Id: number, private isAlive: boolean){}

    array1?: string[];
}
```

Imagine that
the array is initialized with a bunch of data from an API response. I have an array of Test objects. What I now need is to extract the Name of all those objects in that array into a new array.
I could not find typescript syntax for this problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array)

Answer (score 4):

Typescript is (more or less) a superset of javascript. The same solution for Javascript would apply to Typescript.

```
const output = input.map( item => item.name );
```

Answer (score 2):

> What I now need is to extract the Name of all those objects in that array into a new array

Use `Array.prototype.map` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

## Fix

From `Name[]` you want `string[]`:

```
const array1: string[] = names.map(x=>x.fieldThatIsTheStringYouWant);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var originalObject = [
        {"first":"Gretchen","last":"Kuphal","email":"greenwolf54@gmail.com","address":"416 
                            Lesch Road","created":"March 1, 2012","balance":"$9,782.26"}];
```

1.you want to copy array simply

`var duplicateObject = originalObject;`

2. If you want all you can loop
3. If you want access one value simply do this

`duplicateObject[0].first`

`alert(duplicateObject[0].first);`

Editrd
This can be done also

```
var originalObject = [
  {"first":"Gretchen","last":"Kuphal","email":"greenwolf54@gmail.com","address":"416 Lesch Road","created":"March 1, 2012","balance":"$9,782.26"},
{"first":"Morton","last":"Mayer","email":"salmonsquirrel25@gmail.com","address":"1602 Bernhard Parkway","created":"April 29, 2017","balance":"$6,596.11"},
{"first":"Catalina","last":"Daugherty","email":"Catalina.Daugherty@filomena.name","address":"11893 Kali Vista","created":"October 16, 2008","balance":"$6,372.86"},
{"first":"Orpha","last":"Heaney","email":"turquoisewolf22@gmail.com","address":"8090 Chris Stream","created":"November 21, 2015","balance":"$9,596.26"},
{"first":"Reva","last":"Mohr","email":"Reva.Mohr@oda.net","address":"0291 Kailyn Stravenue","created":"November 6, 2014","balance":"$4,768.37"},
{"first":"Loma","last":"Keeling","email":"turquoisegiraffe09@gmail.com","address":"84460 Samson Knoll","created":"June 13, 2017","balance":"$9,361.16"}
];

var duplicateObject=new Array(); 

for (let num of originalObject) {
    duplicateObject.push(num.first);
}
// print
for (let first of duplicateObject) {
    console.log(first);
}
```